Getting "error: cannot satify dependencies" when trying to install deb
I installed kubuntu 24.04, with all the updates, and tried to install the Libre Office 24.2.6.2 offline help file deb and got the "error: cannot satisfy dependencies". What must I do to get the deb files installed? I encountered the problem with the ZOOM deb file.
